# Is there an alternative to Microsoft's ALTools? (EventCombMT.exe especially)

Tags: windows, active-directory, utilities

I use Microsoft's ALTools on a regular basis to troubleshoot multiple different issues. Lately, however, EventCombMT.exe has been crashing on me during the simplest operations. I noticed that it hasn't been updated for a very long time. Is Microsoft recommending that people use a different set of tools? Is there a better alternative out there?

Comment: I don't know what Windows Server version you are using. I am not familiar with ALTools specifically, but it looks like the EventCombMT is for sifting through event logs.  What are you trying to troubleshoot specifically?  Have you done any updates recently?  Added a newer server?

Comment: I use EventCombMT on a regular basis. Troubleshooting repeated account lockouts is one of the scenarios where it's most useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try running eventcombmt from another machine first to check if you have issues with the using the tool elsewhere. The tool is deprecated and there is no known replacement AFAIK.

I did see recently another free 3rd party tool advertised on a well known forum activedir.org. Its http://zetetic.net/products/events . I havent used it myself and am not sure if it will meet your needs.

Comment: This looks promising. There are some bugs with gathering events from server 2003, but overall it seems like a good piece of software. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download [v5 of the tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18465) from Microsoft.

The original version of the tool that is bundled with Windows 2003 Resource Kit is a little, um, quirky.

Also, when it crashes, check to see that you don't have file handles open to the files that it wants to create. That can cause the tool to go belly up. This usually happens when multiple instances are running.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the EventViewer isn't open, I've found that this can cause EventCombMT to crash.